# I want to know this cause and solution

Tags: c++, makefile, cmake

[  6%] Built target ChainedLib

[ 12%] Built target ChainedApp

[ 15%] Linking CXX executable ColorConsole

/usr/bin/ld: cannot open output file ColorConsole: Is a directory

collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

make[2]: *** [ColorConsole] 오류 1

make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/ColorConsole.dir/all] 오류 2

make: *** [all] 오류 2

I install plog library. 
cmake CMakeList.txt complete. but, makefile is fail
I don't know cause

Comment: The error is right there.  It's trying to link an executable named `ColorConsole`, but there is a directory called that in the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a directory called `ColorConsole`. The makefile tries to produce a file with that name. The solution is most likely to remove (or rename) the directory.